# Viewport JQuery - change document ready to if element is in viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

While working on a bigger project I made a box with different content.

The box is 1000px width and shows 5 (out of 50) pictures. The box pages swtich from the first 5 to the next 5 and so on every 8 seconds (already wrote this with jQuery animated).

Now my problem is, that the Box is in the middle of my page, so when visitors stay at the top and scroll down like 30 seconds later they miss the first pictures in my Box.

So my plan is it to start the paging of my box at the very moment the visitor can see the box (viewport).

i made a test page for that

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box">THIS BOX<br>THIS BOX<br>THIS BOX</div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>

.box {
    border:2px solid black;
    height: 400px; 
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/H9xr8/

so far Iam using

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    getThemenCount();
    moveThemenAnimate();
});
```

My plan is to switch from the document ready to a `if element is in viewport` kind of thing

I've aleasy tried to find different ways but i cant seem to get it working.

http://jsfiddle.net/moagrius/wN7ah/

is only working with different classes and with clicks.

What i want to do (and what i cant get working) is that i want to start my animation script in the very Moment the Box gets in the viewpoer of the visitor. So that he will see my pictures in the box starting from picture 1.

is there any possibility to get this to work like I planed it? somehow I cant find out how to set the jQuery expression + the script to work from itself only if i use classes and clicks (like in the fiddle above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen for the `window` `scroll` event, and fire a callback to check if the box is in the viewport yet.

Listening to the `scroll` event can be dangerous from a performance aspect, as naturally the callback will fire whenever the user is scrolling. It's considered best practise to limit the times the callback is fired using a throttling mechanic.

This working example checks the user scroll position 4 times every second, and disables the event listener once the box has appeared in view.

http://jsfiddle.net/H9xr8/1/

```
// document ready
$(function () {

    // define the isOnScreen plugin from http://jsfiddle.net/moagrius/wN7ah/
    $.fn.isOnScreen = function() {
        var win = $(window);

        var viewport = {
            top : win.scrollTop(),
            left : win.scrollLeft(),
            right: win.scrollLeft() + win.width(),
            bottom: win.scrollTop() + win.height()
        };

        var bounds = this.offset();
        bounds.right = bounds.left + this.outerWidth();
        bounds.bottom = bounds.top + this.outerHeight();

        return (!(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right || viewport.bottom < bounds.top || viewport.top > bounds.bottom)); 
    };

    // define throttling function for use in scroll event listener
    // ref: http://blogorama.nerdworks.in/javascriptfunctionthrottlingan/
    function throttle(delay, callback) {
        var previousCall = new Date().getTime();
        return function() {
            var time = new Date().getTime();
            if ((time - previousCall) >= delay) {
                previousCall = time;
                callback.apply(null, arguments);
            }
        };
    }

    // set up an event to listen for window scroll 4 times a second
    $(window).on('scroll', throttle( 250, function () {

        // if #the-box is visible the call init functions and disable window scroll
        // event listener, as you only want to initialise the lightbox once
        if ( $("#the-box").isOnScreen() ) {

            // for demo purposes
            alert('init');

            // call your init functions here
            //getThemenCount();
            //moveThemenAnimate();

            // turn off scroll listener
            $(window).off('scroll');
        }
    }));
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. thats a realy nice code. i like the idea with the throttling. its working perfect on my page

Answer (score 1):

Based on what has been posted, this could be a simple working example,

http://jsbin.com/majavubu/1/edit

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(".the-box").isOnScreen()){
      if(!animationStarted){
        startAnimation();
      }
  }else{
    stopAnimation();
  }
  });
});

var animationStarted=false;
function startAnimation(){
  animationStarted = true;
  for(var i=0;i<10&&animationStarted;i++){
    $(".the-box").animate({"background-color":randomColor()}).delay(500);
  }
}

function stopAnimation(){
  animationStarted = false;
  $(".the-box").stop();
  $(".the-box").css("background-color","white");
}

$.fn.isOnScreen = function(){

    var win = $(window);

    var viewport = {
        top : win.scrollTop(),
        left : win.scrollLeft()
    };
    viewport.right = viewport.left + win.width();
    viewport.bottom = viewport.top + win.height();

    var bounds = this.offset();
    bounds.right = bounds.left + this.outerWidth();
    bounds.bottom = bounds.top + this.outerHeight();

    return (!(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right || viewport.bottom < bounds.top || viewport.top > bounds.bottom));

};



function randomColor(){return '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);}
```

Comment: I'd recommend adding a throttling mechanic to this approach to prevent the callback firing on every traversal of the event loop while the user is scrolling. See my answer for an example and http://blogorama.nerdworks.in/javascriptfunctionthrottlingan/ for an explanation.

Comment: @tommarshall thanks for the article, it is a good one and i agree with this concept. However in this case there is no expensive call happening just calculating the position of the window and compare it with the position of the element, this is simpler that the logic of throttling (the code posted related to the `isOnScreen` function could be simplified to optionally not calculate the position of the element if passed as params, as it does not move, also the size of the viewport could also be optional and recalculated if the window has been resized http://api.jquery.com/resize/) .